# R.layout.activity_main add LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I have a layout  `R.layout.activity_main`, to this layout i have to add another one but using java code.

So i have implemented something like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams match_parent = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(match_parent);
```

So to `R.layout.activity_main`, I need to add the code above.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

in Your activity do something along this lines:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams match_parent = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(match_parent);
    ViewGroup group = findViewById(R.id.id_where_you_wanna_add_your_layout);
    group.addView(layout)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your xml of `R.layout.activity_main` and get the parent `ViewGroup` root id to `activity` .Using `ViewGroup` or its subclasses(`RelativeLayout`,`LinearLayout` etc) add your new layout.

```
//root ViewGroup of your R.layout.activity_main
YourParentLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_parent_layout_id)
//layout is your new LinearLayout
parentLayout.addView(layout)
```